Can I run a GitHub action using codespace prebuilt image?
I have a .devcontainer configuration set up in my GitHub repo, so that all the developers share the same dev environment.
Now I would like the same environment to be used by the GitHub actions runners, too - so that we have full consistency between the 'prod build' environment and the dev environment.
Since building the dev container image from scratch takes a while (~40 min), this needs to be cached. I was hoping we could use the Codespaces prebuilt images to start as a base (e.g. instead of doing runs on: ubuntu-latest, we would do runs on: latest-codespace-devcontainer).
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

To use the same dev environment for GitHub Actions and cache the dev container, you can do the following,

Build and push the dev container image to a container registry (like GitHub Container Registry or Docker Hub).
In your GitHub Actions workflow, pull that prebuilt image instead of building from scratch.
Use docker/build-push-action to cache layers or pull directly from the registry for faster runs.

Unfortunately, there is no direct integration to use Codespaces prebuilt images in Actions, so pushing your own prebuilt image is the way to go
